# start broadcastreceiver

Tags: android

Here I am trying to read the message and toast it I have seen various examples where there is a separate class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` but they have not mentioned how to start this class(do we use startactivity() or somthing else). I have posted the code that I dowladed through a link from O'Reilly's cookbook. I've tried to sms from ddms but it doesn't show toast of message. Any help is appreciated as this is my first time with BroadcastReceiver.

**invitationSMSreciever.java**

```
package com.SMS;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class invitationSMSreciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final String TAG = "BombDefusalApp";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String message = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                message = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (msgs[i].getMessageBody().equalsIgnoreCase("Invite")) {
                    // Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainMenu.this,
                    // com.bombdefusal.ReceivedSMSActivity.class);
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    myIntent.setAction("com.example.helloandroid.INVITE");
                    context.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainMenu**

```
package com.SMS;

import com.SMS.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

**ReceivedSMSActivity**

```
package com.SMS;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

import com.SMS.R;

public class ReceivedSMSActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startService(new Intent ("com.android.PLAY"));
        setContentView(R.layout.invite);
    }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent service) {
        stopService(new Intent("com.bombdefusal.START_AUDIO_SERVICE"));
        finish();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.SMS" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainMenu" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.SMS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.SMS.ReceivedSMSActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.helloandroid.INVITE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.SMS.invitationSMSreciever"
                  android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>          
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to do this:

1. Register you broadcast receiver statically in the AndroidManifest file. Thus, it will be called automatically.
2. Register you broadcast receiver dynamically in your code using `registerReceiver()` method. In this case, this method should be paired with `unregisterReceiver()` where you unregister your receiver.

Usually, if broadcast receiver is implemented as a separate class then it usually registered statically in AndroidManifest file. I guess in you case you should just add the following lines to your file:

```
<receiver android:name=".invitationSMSreciever" android:exported="true" > 
  <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Comment: @Yuri i ve attached the manifest file as you can see a receiver is registered in manifest still it is not working and plz could you explain or answer how to initaite the code of the broadcastreceiver class

Comment: Android system calls method onReceive of your broadcast receiver, when it obtains an intent that corresponds to the intent-filter, which you defined in AndroidManifest.xml. Do you receive the sms sent from ddms by a default messanger application of your emulator? If not, then the problem is not in your code.

Comment: @Yuri yes i am able  to receive message on emulator sent by DDMS

Comment: @Yuri if you have gone through the code Mainmenu(starting activity) does not contain any code to start the invitationSMSreciever class

Comment: Try instead of  Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); just print message into the log: Log.d("MY_SMS", message);